# Extract the values of a dataframe that correspond to a single element of another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, information-retrieval

I have 2 pandas dfs (df1 & df2) as seen here:

| df1 | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row1 | Dog | Cat | Bird | Tree | Lion |
| row2 | Cat | Dragon | Bird | Dog | Tree |
| row3 | Cat | Dog | Bird | Tree | Hippo |
| row4 | Cat | Tree | Bird | Ant | Fish |
| row5 | Cat | Tree | Monkey | Dragon | Ant |

| df2 | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row1 | 3.219843 | 1.3631996 | 1.0051135 | 0.89303696 | 0.4313375 |
| row2 | 2.8661892 | 1.4396228 | 0.7863044 | 0.539315 | 0.48167187 |
| row3 | 2.5679462 | 1.3657334 | 0.9470184 | 0.79186934 | 0.48637152 |
| row4 | 3.631389 | 0.94815284 | 0.7561722 | 0.6743943 | 0.5441728 |
| row5 | 2.4727197 | 1.5941181 | 1.4069512 | 1.064051 | 0.48297918 |

The string elements of the df1 correspond to the values of df2. For both dataframes the condition exists that an element (or a value) does not repeat on the same row. But can be repeated on different rows.

For example Dog of row1 = 3.219843, bird of row3 = 0.9470184, bird of row4 = 0.7561722 etc.

I would like to extract the values for all **unique elements** of the 1st df into different arrays. Like:

**Dog = [3.219843, 0.539315, 1.3657334]**

**Cat = [1.3631996, 2.8661892, 2.5679462, 3.631389, 2.4727197]**

etc...

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are df1 and df2 column names for first columns or dataframe names?

Comment: can you provide the dataframe constructors for the inputs?

Comment: @Arkadiusz they are the df names, first col/1st row is where the numbers begin

Comment: @mozway I cannot unfortunately for confidentiality reasons :(

Comment: @Steven I meant of your examples… the current format is ambiguous in terms of columns/index, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your first columns `df1` and `df2` are the index of their respective `df`, we can extract the values for each unique animal in `df1` by using the first `df` as a mask to extract all wanted values from the second one (the result is a new `df` with `NaN` in irrelevant cells, which can be turned into a 1-dimensional array with `.stack().values`).

#### Construct the dataframes

First of, create some test data. Please provide it in a form like this in future posts. That's what @mozway was talking about in the comments. It is [greatly appreciated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

(It's not always the case that somebody is willing to do all the copy-and-pasting necessary to get dataframes up and running for testing.)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = ['row1', 'row2', 'row3', 'row4', 'row5']

data1 = {'col1': ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Cat', 'Cat', 'Cat'],
         'col2': ['Cat', 'Dragon', 'Dog', 'Tree', 'Tree'],
         'col3': ['Bird', 'Bird', 'Bird', 'Bird', 'Monkey'],
         'col4': ['Tree', 'Dog', 'Tree', 'Ant', 'Dragon'],
         'col5': ['Lion', 'Tree', 'Hippo', 'Fish', 'Ant']}

data2 = {'col1': [3.219843, 2.8661892, 2.5679462, 3.631389, 2.4727197],
         'col2': [1.3631996, 1.4396228, 1.3657334, 0.94815284, 1.5941181],
         'col3': [1.0051135, 0.7863044, 0.9470184, 0.7561722, 1.4069512],
         'col4': [0.89303696, 0.539315, 0.79186934, 0.6743943, 1.064051],
         'col5': [0.4313375, 0.48167187, 0.48637152, 0.5441728, 0.48297918]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, index=index)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, index=index)
```

#### Extract the data

Since you didn't specify what data structure you need, this is the strategy outlined above in a `dict` comprehension:

```py
{animal: df2[df1.eq(animal)].stack().values for animal in np.unique(df1)}
```

The result looks like this:

```py
{'Ant': array([0.6743943 , 0.48297918]),
 'Bird': array([1.0051135, 0.7863044, 0.9470184, 0.7561722]),
 'Cat': array([1.3631996, 2.8661892, 2.5679462, 3.631389 , 2.4727197]),
 'Dog': array([3.219843 , 0.539315 , 1.3657334]),
 'Dragon': array([1.4396228, 1.064051 ]),
 'Fish': array([0.5441728]),
 'Hippo': array([0.48637152]),
 'Lion': array([0.4313375]),
 'Monkey': array([1.4069512]),
 'Tree': array([0.89303696, 0.48167187, 0.79186934, 0.94815284, 1.5941181 ])}
```

Comment: thanks for providing the constructors. Regarding your answer, keep in mind that it will be inefficient to re-filter the dataframe for each animal (O(n*m) complexity, when you can achieve it in O(n)).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the input kindly provided by @fsimonjetz, you can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) both dataframes, then [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) as list:

```
df2.stack().groupby(df1.stack()).agg(list).to_dict()
```

or, using an intermediate DataFrame:

```
(pd
 .concat([df1.stack(),df2.stack()], axis=1)
 .groupby(0)[1].agg(list)
 .to_dict()
)
```

output:

```
{'Ant': [0.6743943, 0.48297918],
 'Bird': [1.0051135, 0.7863044, 0.9470184, 0.7561722],
 'Cat': [1.3631996, 2.8661892, 2.5679462, 3.631389, 2.4727197],
 'Dog': [3.219843, 0.539315, 1.3657334],
 'Dragon': [1.4396228, 1.064051],
 'Fish': [0.5441728],
 'Hippo': [0.48637152],
 'Lion': [0.4313375],
 'Monkey': [1.4069512],
 'Tree': [0.89303696, 0.48167187, 0.79186934, 0.94815284, 1.5941181]}
```